# C# Proper multitasking

Tags: c#, task

I have simple console app which handles some time consuming routine using tasks. While task is running Console shows the user some string indicating that job is being processed.
The following code works pretty well. However I am not sure it is written properly. I wonder is there any way to make it more elegant. Any advices on code refactoring are appriciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //some time consuming job simulation
        Action routine = () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(700);
            }
        };


        Program program = new();
        program.AwaitRoutine(routine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public void AwaitRoutine(Action function, string screenFlag = "Processing")
    {
        Task task = new Task(function);
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        bool isrunning = true;
        task.Start();
        Console.Write(screenFlag);

        while (isrunning)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Write(".");
                if (task.IsCompleted) { isrunning = false; break; }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.CursorLeft = screenFlag.Length;
            Console.Write("   ");
            Console.CursorLeft = screenFlag.Length;
        }

        task.Wait();
        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is _not_ a good substitute for a real-world `Task`  because `Thread.Sleep` blocks the thread, whereas most `async` methods in .NET are IO-bound and so don't block the thread: they yield to the thread-pool instead. Consider using `await Task.Delay` instead. I'll concede that `Thread.Sleep` could be used to imitate CPU-bound work, but be very, very, very careful with it.

Comment: You are instantiating the program class (entry class) which is not good practice. To get around this, consider making the AwaitRoutine function static so that an object refrence is not required and you can just call it directly.